Spring integration AMQP from 2.x to 5.X
I'm migrating my spring web mvc app
spring from 4.x to 5.3.39 and spring integration from 2.x to 5.5.20..
I'm getting the below error from spring integration amqp.
22:55:46 [taskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.core.log.LogAccessor.info 292] LOG_TYPE=LOG|DATE=2024-12-16|TIME=22:55:46.390|APP_NAME=YOUR_APP|HOSTNAME=YOUR_HOST| - GenericMessage [payload=[GenericMessage [payload=byte[2116], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=queueName, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=queueName, amqp_redelivered=false, id=some-id-123, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-xyz123, timestamp=1734369946387}]], headers={id=unique-id-456, timestamp=1734369946387}]
22:55:46 [taskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.core.log.LogAccessor.info 174] LOG_TYPE=LOG|DATE=2024-12-16|TIME=22:55:46.393|APP_NAME=YOUR_APP|HOSTNAME=YOUR_HOST| - Overriding default instance of MessageHandlerMethodFactory with provided one.
22:55:46 [taskExecutor-1] ERROR c.y.p.m.h.e.MessageErrorHandler.handleError 18] LOG_TYPE=LOG|DATE=2024-12-16|TIME=22:55:46.436|APP_NAME=YOUR_APP|HOSTNAME=YOUR_HOST| - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@abc123]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[GenericMessage [payload=byte[2116], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=queueName, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=queueName, amqp_redelivered=false, id=some-id-123, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-xyz123, timestamp=1734369946387}]], headers={id=unique-id-456, timestamp=1734369946387}]
22:55:46 [taskExecutor-1] ERROR o.s.a.r.l.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler 1463] LOG_TYPE=LOG|DATE=2024-12-16|TIME=22:55:46.451|APP_NAME=YOUR_APP|HOSTNAME=YOUR_HOST| - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: null
    at com.example.error.handler.MessageErrorHandler.handleError(MessageErrorHandler.java:19) ~[your-app-service-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ...



ERROR c.example.handler.MessageErrorHandler.handleError - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:471)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:113)

Here is my configuration details
<!-- Services -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="InputChannelA"
    output-channel="OutputChannelB" ref="serviceProcessorA" method="handleTransaction" />

<!-- Routers -->
<int:router id="Router1" input-channel="OutputChannelB"
    ref="routerProcessorA" method="routeToNext">
</int:router>

<int:router id="Router2" input-channel="DatabaseRouteChannel"
    ref="routerProcessorB" method="routeToDatabase">
</int:router>

<!-- Transformers -->
<int:transformer id="DataTransformer" ref="dataTransformerProcessor"
    input-channel="TransformerInputChannel" method="transformData"
    output-channel="DatabaseRouteChannel"></int:transformer>

<!-- Service Activators -->
<int:service-activator id="processActivityDetails"
    input-channel="DetailsProcessingChannel" output-channel="ActivityInsertRequestChannel"
    expression="payload.getContext().getDetails()" />
<int:service-activator id="processExceptionDetails"
    input-channel="ExceptionProcessingChannel" output-channel="ExceptionInsertRequestChannel"
    expression="payload.getContext().getExceptionDetails()" />

<int:service-activator id="insertActivityDetails"
    input-channel="ActivityInsertRequestChannel" output-channel="FinalChannel"
    ref="serviceProcessorA" method="insertDetails" />
<int:service-activator id="insertExceptionDetails"
    input-channel="ExceptionInsertRequestChannel"
    output-channel="FinalChannel" ref="serviceProcessorB" method="insertException" />

<!-- Logging -->
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="LoggingChannelAdapter"
    log-full-message="true" level="INFO" />


It was working fine but when moved to 5.x both spring and integration getting this error.

You don't show your AMQP inbound channel adapter. And that is strange structure of your inbound message: GenericMessage [payload=[GenericMessage. Why the message is wrapped into a payload of another message? I also think that there is supposed to be more in that stack trace to determine what exactly channel and its subscriber is guilty.

@ArtemBilan - I have SimpleMessageListenerContainer  bean with all the properties and id I'm passing it to <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter and  one thing I noticed when I have consumerBatchEnabled=true for batch I'm getting this error.

I see private BatchMode batchMode = BatchMode.MESSAGES; is there by default. So, yeah, that is expected to have a message of messages in that batch mode. So, now your <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter> emits one message for the whole batch, and apparently some your service activator is not ready for that. So, or you need <splitter> in between, or your service activator method must be like this List<Message<?>> to satisfy whatever is emitted from that AMQP inbound channel adapter.
