Spring AMQP consumerBatchEnabled not working
I recently discovered that tx-size has been deprecated in favor of batch-size. I am also migrating the application to Spring 5.3.39 and Spring Integration 5.5.20. Previously, I was using tx-size, but now I plan to change it to batch-size.
<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="queueNames" value="${amqp.queue.name}" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${amqp.consumer.count}" />
    <property name="prefetchCount" value="2" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
    <property name="channelTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="acknowledgeMode" value="AUTO" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="messageErrorHandler" />
    <property name="batchSize" value="2" />
    <property name="consumerBatchEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000" /> 
</bean>

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="amqpAdapter" 
    channel="weChatQueueChannel"
    listener-container="listenerContainer" />

In the above configuration when I include the<property name="consumerBatchEnabled" value="true" /> attribute I'm getting the run time error.
16:33:17 [taskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.core.log.LogAccessor.info 292] LOG_TYPE=TEST|DATE=2024-12-18|TIME=16:33:17.269|APP_NAME=APP|HOSTNAME=HOST-019| - GenericMessage [payload=[GenericMessage [payload=byte[2116], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=testExchange, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=testExchange,, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=testExchange,, x-first-death-exchange=, x-death=[{reason=expired, count=1, exchange=deadletterExchange, routing-keys=[TestQueue], time=Wed Dec 18 16:32:22 IST 2024, queue=deadletterQueue}, {reason=rejected, count=1, exchange=, time=Wed Dec 18 16:29:22 IST 2024, routing-keys=[testExchange], queue=testExchange}], x-first-death-reason=rejected, x-first-death-queue=testExchange, id=9da93360-4213-8811-9766-cf5421df751e, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-YDnXDG46SewEL-tYu2DNgQ, timestamp=1734519797266}]], headers={id=8104fb98-322f-a695-e37e-60f2604a192d, timestamp=1734519797266}]
16:33:17 [taskExecutor-1] INFO  o.s.core.log.LogAccessor.info 174] LOG_TYPE=TEST|DATE=2024-12-18|TIME=16:33:17.271|APP_NAME=APP|HOSTNAME=HOST-019| - Overriding default instance of MessageHandlerMethodFactory with provided one.
16:33:17 [taskExecutor-1] ERROR c.a.m.h.e.MessageErrorHandler.handleError 17] LOG_TYPE=TEST|DATE=2024-12-18|TIME=16:33:17.307|APP_NAME=APP|HOSTNAME=HOST-019| - An error occurred while processing the message: {}
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@6981845b]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    -------
    --------
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:471)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:358)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:110)
    ... 30 common frames omitted


If I take out the enable batching attribute still the batching works as expected?
Why the program is throwing an error if include the consumerBatchEnabled attribute?

Feel like duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79285614/spring-integration-amqp-from-2-x-to-5-x
